# Attribute application@label value=(AOL) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-28

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run the app on emulator but I found the below error:

```
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :connectivity_macos not found. Please update settings.gradle.
D:\Aradi Online\AOL\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-28 Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(AOL) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-28
    is also present at [org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.1-2] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-53:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(AOL) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-28
    is also present at [org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.1-2] AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-53:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and here's the `Manifest`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.AOL">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="AOL"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and here's the build gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.AOL"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and this is my `yaml`:

```
name: aol
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  shared_preferences: 0.5.7+3
  cached_network_image: 2.2.0+1
  flutter_cache_manager: 1.2.2 #for cached_network_image
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: 4.1.2
  connectivity: 0.4.8+6
  dynamic_theme: 1.0.1
  sembast: 2.4.4+1
  path_provider: 1.6.9
  intl: 0.16.1
  shimmer: 1.1.1
  smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1
  url_launcher: 5.4.10
  carousel_slider: 2.1.0
  firebase_core: 0.4.5
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.16
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1 # firebase_auth is for phone login
  admob_flutter: 0.3.4
  firebase_database: 3.1.6
  google_sign_in: 4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0
  photo_view: 0.9.2
  progress_dialog: 1.2.3
  braintree_payment: 1.2.4
  easy_localization: 2.3.2
  launch_review: 2.0.0
  package_info: 0.4.0+18
  flutter_icons: 1.1.0
  stripe_payment: 1.0.7
  flutter_credit_card: 0.1.3
  fluttertoast: 4.0.1
  permission_handler: 5.0.0+hotfix.6
  flutter_map: 0.9.0
  latlong: 0.6.1
  geocoder: 0.2.1
  multi_image_picker: 4.6.7
  flutter_widget_from_html: 0.3.3+4
  esys_flutter_share: 1.0.2
  apple_sign_in: 0.1.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I feel that there's something missing in the `Manifest` or the `build.gradle`.................

I hope someone could help me to figure this error, sorry if there's something missing or not clear....................

Comment: This *may* help. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2599

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thank you very much the first part of the error was gone, now I am still stuck on the second part :D